# VBA Can I count the number of times I call a function in my Script

Tags: vba

I'm trying to build a dynamic progress bar in Excel, and the way I'm currently doing this is by hard-coding a number of steps into my script as the "total number of steps"... the Application.StatusBar code gets updated with a counter that is divided by this total.

What I'd like to do is to have "TotalSteps" pre-populate with 3 (using the example below) by searching ahead through the code to identify the number of times "Call fnProgress" appears in the subroutine.

```
Public Sub Example()
    TotalSteps = 3     'Enter a value here equal to the number of times "Call fnProgress" appears below

    Call ABC
    Call fnProgress

    Call 123
    Call fnProgress

    Call DoReMi
    Call fnProgress
End Sub
```

I don't get the impression this is possible in VBA, but I figured someone here would know how to do it if it was! Or perhaps someone could offer a better solution to my simple progress bar... Being able to search ahead in the actual code is also an interesting problem, to me, and I'd imagine it's got further application beyond my status bar.
Thanks so much!
-Julia :)

Comment: Those 'Calls' are to sub procedures, not functions.

Comment: I generally default to writing functions because most of what I need then to do is to return a value, but I suppose sub procedure/subroutine is probably more common.

Comment: Ah! Call! This negates the return on a function... Thank you, I had been working under the wrong assumption for all this time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it's not pretty.
I would consider the solution below bad practice in most cases. Anyway - here it goes:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim StepCount As Integer
    Dim TotalSteps As Integer
    Steps = Array("Abc", "Def", "Ghi")
    TotalSteps = UBound(Steps) + 1
    For Each Step In Steps
        StepCount = StepCount + 1
        ActiveSheet.Evaluate Step & "()+0" '+0 is workaround to handle a bug in VBA. Without it, the method is called twice
        Progress StepCount, TotalSteps
    Next
End Sub

Sub Progress(StepCount As Integer, TotalSteps As Integer)
    Debug.Print StepCount & "(" & TotalSteps & ")"
End Sub

Sub Abc()
    Debug.Print "Abc"
End Sub

Sub Def()
    Debug.Print "def"
End Sub

Sub Ghi()
    Debug.Print "ghi"
End Sub
```

The base for this is the Evaluate function, that allows you to evaluate expressions in strings. The Test method calls the methods in the Steps array, using Evaluate.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I agree it's not really quite what I was hoping I could do. It's almost like I want a VBA function that can search text within the literal VBA code. I doubt if it exists.

Comment: See my other answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach. Not a good way to write code, but again, there are situations where it is warranted.

Start by adding a reference to *Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility*, then add this code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Set CodeMod = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule

    Debug.Print CountOccurrences("Call fnProgress", CodeMod.Lines(1, CodeMod.CountOfLines)) - 1 'Remove 1 to ignore this line
End Sub

Function CountOccurrences(SoughtString As String, InString As String) As Long
    CountOccurrences = (Len(InString) - (Len(Replace(InString, SoughtString, "")))) / Len(SoughtString)

End Function
```

The module name is hardcoded. It reads the code, counts the number of occurences of `Call  fnProgress` and subtracts one (so that the count it self isn't counted). Adjust as needed.